# how to define vector<ifstream> in c++ class

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I need a vector member in class like this:

```
class A
{
private:
vector<ifstream> _files;
public:
bool addFile(const string& filePath);
};

bool A::addFile(const string& filePath)
{
ifstream ifile(filePath.c_str());
_files.push_back(ifile);//but errors;
}
```

How can I finished this class with successful compilation;

Now my solution is use vector. is that ok? or some potential danger?

Answer (score 2):

STL container needs element to be **CopyConstructible** and **Assignable** . `std::ifstream` is not copyable. you need to use a smart pointer to `std::ifstream` instead.

Comment: If you have access to `std::unique_ptr`, you can already store them in a vector.

Comment: It won't be dangerous. you'd better use a smart pointer to store it.